# Appeared window when you click button HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am new in HTML/CSS, how to make a small window that appears when you click on some button or link. For example like on this kind of https://movie-chooser.co.ua When you click "Info" button on a movie card.
[Photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS9ez.png)

Comment: look it - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: these "windows" are called modals. Bootstrap has a good native support for it. Just read the documentation, it is well described how to implement and there are tons of examples on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Modal</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          This is a modal. Edit it however you want.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can modify it however you want.

Comment: So much code in here... I think there must be an easier way to do it with bootsrap

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to this with pure CSS is to create a separate container with a class of popup and then inside of it a separate container with a content (for the popup).
You should set background of the popup parent container to `rgba(black,0.7);` additionally, you would want to set `visibility:hidden; opacity:0` .
Set the `id="popup"` to the parent container (so, you have id and class of "popup").

The clickable element (on which you click and the popup shows) should be an anchor tag with the `href="#popup"`, like so: `<a href="#popup">Info</a>`. Afterwards, make a use of `:target` pseudoclass in CSS. The code will look like:

```
.popup{
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: rgba(black, 0.7);
   z-index: 100;
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
 }

 .popup:target {
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible
  }
```

To close the popup window, the "x" button on the right upper corner should be an anchor tag with the `href="#home_page"`. You should give the home page section the `id="home_page"`. So, you are basically redirecting to Home page.